# How to restart mehthod in Java?

Tags: java, methods

At the end of the game I want the method to restart. I added a loop but it won't do what I want it to do. Calling the main method using `main();` results in an error. How do I restart the method?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        //A ton of stuff has been emitted here

        randomNumber = randomGenerate.nextInt(1000) + 1;

        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 1000: ");
        guess = inputGenerate.nextInt();

        while(truth) {
            while (randomNumber != guess) {
                if (guess < randomNumber) {
                    System.out.println("Too low! Try higher: ");
                    guess = inputGenerate.nextInt();
                }
                if (guess > randomNumber) {
                    System.out.println("Too high! Try lower: ");
                    guess = inputGenerate.nextInt();
                }
            }

            if (guess == randomNumber) {
                System.out.println("Correct! Nicely done :)");
                System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (yes/no): ");
                answer = inputGenerateString.nextLine();
                if (answer.equals("no")) {
                    System.out.println("Too bad! Thanks for playing though:)");
                    break;
                }
                else if(answer.equals("yes")) {
                    System.out.println("Alright, here we go again!");

                  //Here I want to restart the method

                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of _truth_ variable and how do you set that?

Answer (score 0):

You already have an infinite loop, except that it should be `while(true)` and not `while(truth)`. You can simply regenerate your random number and ask the user for their guess and let the loop take care care of repeating the query for user input like:

```
while(true) {
    while (randomNumber != guess) {
        ... omitted for brevity ...
    }

    if (guess == randomNumber) {

        ... omitted for brevity ...
        if (answer.equals("no")) {
            System.out.println("Too bad! Thanks for playing though:)");
            break;
        }
        else if(answer.equals("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Alright, here we go again!");         
            randomNumber = randomGenerate.nextInt(1000) + 1;
            System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 1000: ");
            guess = inputGenerate.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to also emit all the stuff from earlier, I would recommend wrapping it in a function call so it can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `main` by passing it `null` as an argument. be sure to break the loop beforehand, and add a boolean flag to continue the game:

```
private boolean continueFlag = false;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //A ton of stuff has been emitted here

    randomNumber = randomGenerate.nextInt(1000) + 1;

    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 1000: ");
    guess = inputGenerate.nextInt();

    while(truth) {
        while (randomNumber != guess) {
            if (guess < randomNumber) {
                System.out.println("Too low! Try higher: ");
                guess = inputGenerate.nextInt();
            }
            if (guess > randomNumber) {
                System.out.println("Too high! Try lower: ");
                guess = inputGenerate.nextInt();
            }
        }

        if (guess == randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("Correct! Nicely done :)");
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (yes/no): ");
            answer = inputGenerateString.nextLine();
            if (answer.equals("no")) {
                System.out.println("Too bad! Thanks for playing though:)");
                continueFlag = false;
                break;
            }
            else if(answer.equals("yes")) {
                System.out.println("Alright, here we go again!");
                continueFlag = true;
                break;
              //Here I want to restart the method

            }
        }

    }

    if (continueFlag == true) {
        main(null);
    }
}
```

A thing to watch out: make sure `continueFlag` is set to `false` to end the game ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I am guessing that the truth loop is how many guesses that they get and just move the while loop into a method called playgame(int randomNumber, int guess); and it contains the while loop in it.

I would break it into three methods: generateRandomNumberMethod(), getUserInput(), and playGame.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

{
        //A ton of stuff has been emitted here

```
    randomNumber = randomGenerate.nextInt(1000) + 1;

    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 1000: ");
    guess = inputGenerate.nextInt();

   playGame(int generateRandomNumberMethod(), int getUserInput(), int numberOfGuess){
       while( i<=numberOfGuess){

         while (randomNumber != guess) {
            if (guess < randomNumber) {
                System.out.println("Too low! Try higher: ");
                guess = inputGenerate.nextInt();
            }
            if (guess > randomNumber) {
                System.out.println("Too high! Try lower: ");
                guess = inputGenerate.nextInt();
            }
        }

        if (guess == randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("Correct! Nicely done :)");
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (yes/no): ");
            answer = inputGenerateString.nextLine();
            if (answer.equals("no")) {
                System.out.println("Too bad! Thanks for playing though:)");
                break;
            }
            else if(answer.equals("yes")) {
                System.out.println("Alright, here we go again!");

              playGame(new generateRandomNumberMethod(), getUserInput(), int numberofGuess)

            }
         i++
        }
      }
    }
```

}